How can I detach an included navigation property in EF core?
I have the following code:
var items = _context.DbSetName
             .Where(c => ...)
             .Include(c => c.NavigationProperty)
             .AsNoTracking()
             .ToList();

But when I want to update the main entity, I get an error that the entity related to the main entity can't be tracked because an entity with the same id is already being tracked.
So I also tried to detach it manually before updating it and saving it the following way:
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item.NavigationProperty != null)
    {
        _context.Entry(item.NavigationProperty).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    _context.DbSetName.Update(item);
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync(ct);

But I still get the same exception.
The exception occurs during at the Update and not the at the SaveChanges method.

Why not just remove the .AsNoTracking() call?

You would probably be best using the EF change tracking here, then there's no need to call Update. Remove the .AsNoTracking() from your original query, and then EF will detect any changes made to your entities automatically when you call SaveChangesAsync.

Just don't use DbSet.Update method. Another question is why it's already attached. That may be context lifecycle issue. As you see: there's more to this than meets the eye.
